# python how to check if tuple contains anything from list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, sanitization

I am making a Discord Bot with python, and right now I am making a command where the bot repeats your input if certain requirements are met. Full code for that command is [here](https://mystb.in/ConcludedThemesParticipating.python) (I added commentation). I am working on sanitizing the input, and one part of that checks if there is any bad words used in the input.

The input is a tuple, I made it like that so I can show the first 5 words that were said.

So I want to check if any of those BADWORD_triggers are used in the input, currently I am doing it like this: `elif ' '.join(args) in BADWORD_triggers` However that only checks if the *first* word is one of the triggers. I also tried `elif args in BADWORD_triggers` and `elif BADWORD_triggers in args` which just results in errors.

For other commands I use `def async function(ctx, *, arg)` where I can check if the input contains any of the BADWORD_triggers like this: `if arg in BADWORD_triggers:` because `*, arg` is a string.

So my question is concretely: How do I check if a tuple contains anything from a list.

Example:

Here is I use a badword "bad" as the only and first input, the bot refuses to say it. However I want it to also refuse this, as it contains a bad word.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGquq.jpg

Here I use a badword "bad" but with more input, the message gets deleted
and the bot repeats what I say.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c36IY.jpg

Comment: Not able to understand your problem clearly, Add an Example `Tuple` which you want to match against example `list` and Output in your Question for better explanation

Comment: Sure I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple `function`:

```
def check_bad_words(words):
    for word in words:
        if word in BADWORD_triggers:
            return True
    return False
```

and then in your `elif-statement`:

```
elif check_bad_words(args):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you could define a variable that is set to True if there are badwords:

```
badwords = False
for word in args:
     if word in BADWORD_triggers: badwords = True
```

Answer (score 1):

All I get is you have an following two variables with some input data and Bad words

```
input_tuple = ("Hii", "This", 'Jack')
bad_words_check = ['xyz', 'abc']
```

You can check weather any word of `input_tuple` is present in `bad_words_check` by following as follows

```
for word in input_tuple:
    if word in bad_words_check :
       # add your code for handling bad words
       print("got bad words")
```